# App crash on iPhone when selecting textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a textfield that crashes when I select the textfield to enter text. no keyboard appears and app crashes. Happens on iphones, textfield works fine on iPad.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 140,
  height: 38,
  child: TextField(),
);
```

version:

```
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2d2a1ffec9 (6 days ago) • 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
Engine • revision b863200c37
Tools • Dart 2.5.0
```

stack trace:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0168db __exceptionPreprocess + 331
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d5b9ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e016735 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
        3   UIKitCore                           0x000000011596d303 -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 921
        4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000115b2155d -[UIApplicationRotationFollowingController supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 101
        5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011596d237 -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 717
        6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011596d859 -[UIViewController __withSupportedInterfaceO<…>
```

Tested on iphone 8 simulator (fails), tested on iphone 7 physical device (fails), tested on iPad 2 simulator (works fine)

Comment: try FLUTTER CLEAN command and then re run again
and paste your full code.

Comment: I returned to this issue today to try to reproduce it and post my code and could NOT, when suggested on Sept 14 I tried the flutter clean but it didn't resolve it at the time. Thanks @RutvikGumasana for your response, it probably WAS some sort of compiling issue.

Comment: is your issue solved??

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear from my comment, yes the crash is gone, I will continue to test for this in the future and comment here if it appears again.

Comment: @AaronHalvorsen can you help us, how the crash is gone. It will help us on fixing the same issue.

Comment: @RaghuMudem, I will post the code of the textfield here that now works, it's the best I can do as I don't know why this issue was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the textfield I used to resolve the issue I posted above.

```
SizedBox(
      width: 180,
      height: 28,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
        child: TextField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          onChanged: (searchTerm) => bloc(context).add(SearchEvent(searchTerm)),
          onEditingComplete: () => bloc(context).add(SearchEvent('')),
          onSubmitted: null, //do nothing
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintStyle: textStyle,
            labelStyle: textStyle,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            filled: true,
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: 'Enter search terms',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```